# Exiting while loop bash script from tail

Tags: bash

I have a script that tails a log file, and then uploads the line. I would like to have it exit as soon as the first line is read:

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -n0 -F "$1" | while read LINE; do
  (echo "$LINE" | grep -e "$3") && curl -X POST --silent --data-urlencode \
    "payload={\"text\": \"$(echo $LINE | sed "s/\"/'/g")\"}" "$2";
done
```

Comment: Exit as soon as the first line is read? Or when the first data is uploaded?

Comment: As soon as the first line is read and sent off via curl.

Comment: What if the first line read doesn't match what's passed in as the third arg?

Comment: Right now it uploads on each line added that contains the third arg of the script ($3)

Comment: The third arg is the url to which it writes.
ex: bash log-tail.sh log_4 http://localhost:5000/utils/log/4

Comment: It uploads the second arg ($2). The first arg is the file it's tailing. The third arg is a pattern which grep must match else it won't call `curl`

Comment: Does the answer work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit as soon as the first line is uploaded you can just add a `break`:

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -n0 -F "$1" | while read LINE; do
  (echo "$LINE" | grep -e "$3") && curl -X POST --silent --data-urlencode \
    "payload={\"text\": \"$(echo $LINE | sed "s/\"/'/g")\"}" "$2" && break;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the `tail` command wasn't getting killed. A slightly modified version of my script (I didn't end up needing the echo to stdout)

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -n0 -F "$1" | while read LINE; do
    curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"text\": \"$(echo $LINE | sed "s/\"/'/g")\"}" "$2" && pkill -P $$ tail
done
```

This answer helped as well: https://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found